# Having Difficulty Getting a Proper Redirect from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am having difficulty getting a proper redirect from `.htaccess`.  The redirect that I am attempting is the following:

Original URL:

`http://www.mysite.com/index.php/contact-us?id=12`

Should Direct to:

`http://www.mysite.com/index.php/new-contact-request-form`

I have attempted a variety of variations on the following samples with no luck.  Any ideas on where I’m going wrong?

Example 1:

```
Redirect /index.php/contact-us?id=12 http://www.mysite.com/index.php/new-contact-request-form
```

Example 2:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php/contact-us?id=12$

RewriteRule ^index\.php\/new\-contact\-request\-form$ http://www.mysite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Example 3:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com\/index\.php\/contact\-us\?id\=12$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/index\.php\/new\-contact\-request\-form" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL structure:
 [image]

`%{QUERY_STRING}` variable contains the url query string (which is in our case id=12),

in the other hand, `RewriteRule` operates on the url path only (not including the query string),

so basically , the code below check if the query string is equal to `id=12` and if the url path is equal to `index.php/contact-us` , if so, a redirection will take place

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=12$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/contact\-us$ /index.php/new-contact-request-form? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer, please? Thanks.

Comment: I've added some explanation, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for this through answer.  I believe that I almost have it worked out.  I have attempted the sample you provided:

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=12$`
`RewriteRule ^index\.php/contact\-us$ /index.php/new-contact-request-form [R=301,L]`

The only problem is that the URL is redirect to is keeping the `id=12` query string on the redirected link.  This gives me the following result:

`http://www.mysite.com/index.php/new-contact-request-form?id=12`

I need it to eliminate the query string altogether, what adjustment would be required to fix this?

Comment: adding an `?` at the end of the RewriteRule will fix that (overriding the query string), answer updated.